# What does it mean for go's CompareAndSwap to return false?

Tags: go

There are many atomic operations in the source code of go. For example, `sync.Map` uses a large number of atomic operations, such as `CompareAndSwap`, and `CompareAndSwap` returns a `bool` type value indicating whether it is successful. If successful, it returns true, otherwise it returns false. I have some doubts about this method:

1. Does `CompareAndSwap` return false if the values of compare are not equal?
2. Will `CompareAndSwap` fail if the compared values are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation states, CompareAndSwap is equivalent to:

```
if *addr == old {
    *addr = new
    return true
}
return false
```

So it returns false if the values are not equal, and the swap operation did not take place. This is useful to figure out if some value has changed since the last time it was set, and it if hasn't changed, set it to something else.